# Load external libraries in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundler

The javascript project is using webpack 2 for bundling the scripts. Is there any way the external script can be loaded at run time in browser. Stripe checkout needs to be loaded at runtime only at time of checkout page appears. Is there any way that stripe checkout js can be loaded at time of checkout page is rendered.

Comment: Why can't you just use two script tags on the one page?

Comment: @jhpratt It affects the page speed. For the landing page of the app there is no need to load the stripe js. Do you think its a good idea to load the libraries which the user never users on the page to load it. I think its good to load whenever it is used.

Comment: That's why I'm saying you should have most of the scripts in one combined file, then the stripe library in another. Load whatever you need, at the expense of an extra HTTP request.

Comment: Sure, thank you @jhpratt, If there are any possibility kindly answer.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could use webpack to combine all files *except* the Stripe script. That file can then (presumably) be loaded on every page without overhead, with a second `script` tag for the Stripe file on the one page.

This let's you only load what's needed on every other page in a single request, while still having the Stripe script at the expense of a second request.